# Google geocoding: Place Id are different when geocoding business/company name and address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

**My Problem:**
My scenario is that in my app I have a inputfield, where you can search for addresses which uses autocomplete. In this field you can type in any company name and it will find the lat/long and set the marker on the map below the input. Then the user can also drag and drop the marker somewhere using the map, and here comes the problem, as I cant get the company name this way, which is needed in my requirements. My failed attempts are below.

---

**Finding company name by lat/lon:**  I need to get companyname based on a position (lat/long).

So what I tried is geocode the lat/lon to get the place id:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=55.93366899999999,12.258698299999992&key=xxx

It gives me place_id: "ChIJwSWuIGRAUkYRf7LPSwRStYU"

Then I use that to get place name:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJwSWuIGRAUkYRf7LPSwRStYU&key=xxx

But no place name! The JSON does not contain anything about the business.

---

**Finding company name by address:** So i tried to geocode address instead of lat/long:
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Sigrunsvej%2040%20Hillerød](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Sigrunsvej%2040%20Hiller%C3%B8d)

This gives me place id: ChIJa1mGSGFAUkYR2SpylJRKlLM
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJa1mGSGFAUkYR2SpylJRKlLM&key=xxx

After throwing that into places, the place is the same as before without company name..

---

**Finding company name by "company name":** But when I try to give the company name in the url, I get a 3rd place id:
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Bauhaus%20Hillerød](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Bauhaus%20Hiller%C3%B8d)

Place id: ChIJZWxjtmZAUkYRWY4K-RTjwsk
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJZWxjtmZAUkYRWY4K-RTjwsk&key=xxx

This place id works, and I get the company name "BAUHAUS".

---

**Question:** So how do I get the company name without knowing it already? It also seems crazy to me that one place can have different place ids.

Comment: The reverse geocoder is for retrieving postal addresses.  If you need a business name, use the Places API.

Comment: I'm already looking up in places api when i get the place id

Comment: Searching address on places does not change anything... https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=Sigrunsvej+40+Hiller%C3%B8d&key=xxx

Comment: To get the place I'd for the **business**, you need to do a search for the business name (or a nearbySearch for the coordinates)

Comment: Hi again. My problem is that I dont have the business name. So I dont have that to search for..

Comment: I got it by using placesearch and set the radius to 1.  Please make an answer so I can accept it: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=55.93366899999999,12.258698299999992&radius=1&key=xxx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [nearbySearch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) on the location.

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
var radius = 100;
service.nearbySearch({
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(55.93366899999999, 12.258698299999992),
  radius: radius,
  type: "store"
}, callback);
```

Returns one result:

> BAUHAUS Hillerød
> placeId:ChIJZWxjtmZAUkYRWY4K-RTjwsk

(Note: without the `type:"store"`, I get a different result)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/o1qgsscp/3/)

[image: screenshot]

**code snippet:**

```js
var infowindow;
var map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.93366899999999, 12.258698299999992),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  var radius = 100;
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    center: map.getCenter(),
    radius: radius
  });
  map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: map.getCenter(),
    radius: radius,
    type: "store"
  }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    console.log(results.length + " results");
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  } else console.log("status=" + status);
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name + "<br>placeId:" + place.place_id);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
  google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```